# why redis zrank's complexity is O(log(N))

Tags: algorithm, redis

Redis [zrank](http://redis.io/commands/zrank).

> Returns the rank of member in the sorted set stored at key, with the scores ordered from low to high. The rank (or index) is 0-based, which means that the member with the lowest score has rank 0.

Why the complexity is O(log(N))? The members are sorted by scores, but zrank is queried by member.

### Update

I found something that maybe the answer.

A. when zset is implemented by ziplist

1. The size is less than 128
2. The size of each member is less than 64 bytes.

So, The size of ziplist is small, so it is not the problem I discussed.

B. when zset is implemented by skiplist
The zset's implementation is：

```
typedef struct zset {

    zskiplist *zsl;

    dict *dict;

} zset;
```

The zset keep a dict and a skiplist at the same time.

1. `dict` keeps mapping of member to score.
2. `zsl` is the sorted list of objects which are ordered by scores. The object contain both member and score.

So, `zrank` is like this:

1. use O(1) time to find the score of the member. If not found, return `nil`.
2. search in `zsl` with the found score, take O(log(N)) time.

Comment: You say *use the found score search from zsl, take O(log(N)) time.*, but you can only find the member you want, but you can't know what its rank is.

Comment: @JasonLaw There is a span (int) for each level in skiplist's node. It will be accumulated during search processing. See detail:  zslGetRank in https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/t_zset.c

Answer (score 2):

Most likely that member keys are stored in some kind of search tree (augmented with branch sizes like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)).

So both element searching and rank calculation are performed in O(logN). Link above shows sample implementations of these operations.

Answer (score 2):

Redis uses one of two encodings for Sorted Sets: ziplists and skip lists.

Smaller sets are ziplists and their ranking complexity is actually O(N). However, this is considered as O(1) because of the ziplist threshholds that are constant.

When using skip list encoding, ranking is O(LogN) because that the search's comlexity - refer to the [Wikipedia article about skiplists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) for more information.

Comment: Why is ranking O(LogN) when using skip list encoding? skip list is ordered by score, you can find the member by score using O(LogN), but how do you know the rank of that member?